# addHours, addMinutes function not working in azure data Factory

Tags: timestamp, azure-data-factory

I am trying for a function in order to add some hours to my present existing time zones in order to handle time stamp of various countries.

Would be glad if some one can help me in knowing if any other way of adding hours or minutes to a timestamp.

This question specific to Azure Data Factory

[Function is not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1xWn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory supports many date functions in expression:
[image]

Please ref: [Date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions)

We can use this functions in dynamic content.

This example adds 10 hours to the specified timestamp:

```
addHours('2018-03-15T00:00:00Z', 10)
```

And returns this result: `"2018-03-15T10:00:0000000Z"`

If you want to add some hours to my present existing time zones, the expression should be:

```
addHours(utcNow(), 10)
```

For more details, please ref: [Expressions and functions in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions)

**Update:**

It looks like you are using Data flow. Then you could using [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#add) and [hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#hours):
[image]

Your expression should be something like:

```
currentTimestamp()+hours(2)
```

Comment: But the addHours Function is not visible in the Azure Data Factory and even its not working.

Comment: Hi @YAbhilashReddy, why do you think so?  These functions are in `add dynamic content`.

Comment: used the Function fromUTC(TimeStamp, Zone)

Zone = 'GMT+5:30'

Comment: Can you edit the question and  show us some screenshots?

Comment: @YAbhilashReddy If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.